# Are the resources released once the Kubernetes job is finished if the job is not deleted?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Are the resources released once the kube job is finished?

I mean the associated pod resources, let say a job is run to completion and the associated pod is in a completed state, which was allocated 0.5 CPU, is the 0.5cpu released after the job is finished?

or is it released only after deleting the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **[pod phase](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-phase)** does not include "completed": you only have "Succeeded":

> All Containers in the Pod have terminated in success, and will not be restarted."

Since this is a terminal state, its reserved resources won't be taken into consideration by the scheduler.

Comment: thank you, to summarize, the resources are released and can be used/consumed by other pods or other kubernetes objects

Comment: @CodingNinja Yes, that is the idea.